# Will The Google Home Hub Have An API?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

My Googling is getting me nowhere. Has anyone heard what what publicly accessible APIs will be available for this device? I see it has advertised apps, but I don't know how far they'll go beyond existing Actions, and I'm interested in custom graphical interfaces.
https://store.google.com/us/product/google_home_hub

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Home Hub, like other smart displays, works with [Actions on Google](https://actions.google.com/) to build visually conversational experiences. Additionally, it has a deep visual integration with [smart home](https://developers.google.com/smarthome) to control devices in your home.

Comment: Thanks! As clarification, however, I wondered if it will be possible to have rich controls like an interactive chart or something. Maybe that's already supported in card responses (I'm not that familiar), but either way I wondered if there's a special API that specifically targets the device.

Comment: @prisoner could you point me in the right direction regarding how to create an interface for the google home hub? Is there something like APL which is used for alexa?

Comment: @James - as Nick noted, there are already a number of visual elements which work on both the Hub and other visual platforms (such as the Assistant on Android). Those have been around for a while and they keep adding more, tho it isn't the same as the APL.

Comment: @Colin - As Nick said, there is no API that specifically targets smart displays right now beyond what is available as part of the Actions on Google API. There were some things previewed at I/O, but nothing about them has been announced.

Answer (score 1):

Google added the [interactive canvas](https://developers.google.com/assistant/interactivecanvas), which seems to a be web-based way to present graphical interaction:

> Interactive Canvas is a framework built on the Google Assistant that allows developers to add visual, immersive experiences to conversational Actions. This visual experience is an interactive web app that the Assistant sends as a response to the user in conversation. Unlike traditional rich responses that exist in-line in an Assistant conversation, the Interactive Canvas web app renders as a full-screen web view.
>
> …
>
> Interactive Canvas is currently available on the following devices:
>
> - Smart Displays
> - **Google Nest Hubs**
> - Android mobile devices

Answer (score 0):

"Google Nest Hubs" is *not* an available option anymore on the website you shared.

I found a neat demo of Google Assistant Ecommerce using Interactive Canvas on Nest Hub Max here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYMBOQ46Czw